# Handle Tree Format Array in Table View -objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I have a Json response with tree structure array. Now the problem is i have to display that array in table view. The array format is like
`details =     {
        id = 002;
        name = Rohit;
        fid = 123;
        "Friends" =         (
                        {
                id = 003;
                name = "Sham";
                fid = 2355;
                "Friends" =                 (
                                        {
                        id = 252;
                        name = Ram;
                        Fid = 8568;
                        "Friends" =                         (
                                                        {
                                id = 7545;
                                name = "Rahul";
                                Fid = 874;
                                "Friends" =                                 (
                                );
                            },
                                                        {
                                id = 77554;
                                name = "LCMff";
                                pid = 45425;
                              "Friends"=                                 (
                                );
                            },
                                                        {
                                id = 4545;
                                name = peter;
                                fid = 4548;
                             "Friends"= (
                                         {
                                        id = 785612;
                                        name = "john";
                                        fid = 45;
                                        "Friends" =                                         (
                                        );
                                    }
                                );
                            },`
                            },

Above is the example. Now i have to display Friends list in table view on click of name.Also i have to display the name in header like bread crumb. Help me out to resolve this.